# Html content from Ashx handler does not shown in html source for search index

Tags: jquery, asp.net, httphandler, ashx

I call an ASHX handler through jquery using `dataType: 'html'`, `type: 'GET'` and few parameters.

There are some results which are retrieved from ASHX handler. and using content type 'html', the results (which are mixture of html tags and javascript) are appending (using jquery appendTo) to a div `dvProducts`.
The html and javascript populated from ASHX handler are working fine in each browser. Although while viewing div `dvProducts` in view source, it is empty.
The div can be inspected in chrome or firefox with proper tags and hierarchy underneath.

Basically, it is search for products by name and the handler queries and set the layout to display.

The issue only came when the result div seems empty when view source.
This is needed for google caching and indexing the page.

Please assist in this scenario and suggest if there is any better approach.

Comment: View Source (and goog) only sees what was on the page when it was first loaded.  Do you start with the product list empty because of some requirement?

Comment: nope, the list is populated on page load. Than user can apply certain filters on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to populate your div server side instead of only relying on JavaScript. Refactor your code so you can insert the html via your asp.net template engine. If you're using WebForms, put that code in a User Control and render it from your ashx so it can be retrieved by JavaScript (check out RenderControl). Then go to the User Control/Page that contains the div and insert your new User Control there. Now you can't append the html you retrieve from your ashx - you have to replace the innerHTML of your div with the html from your ashx.

Comment: Jan, the idea was nice.. Unfortunately it isn't working though I tried it by different other techniques. And finally, I intend to use Repeater with jquery from code behind so that page content can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

*"The html and javascript populated from ashx handler are working fine in each browser. Although while viewing div 'dvProducts' in view source, it is empty."*

If you are sure that your handler is working fine, then please have a look in browser console after the request to handler from jquery or use debug tool that are provided with the browser.
Because if your handler is working fine then just appending the handler response to the div shouldn't be an issue.

If you can provide some of your code then it will be easy for the community to guide you in the proper direction

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Ajax generated content is dynamic and can not be index or crawled, have a look in this
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

They have some methods/concepts that may help you